# Translate "Family X Model YY Stepping Z" into unique processor id

Tags: cpuid

Is there any dataset/way to obtain a unique processor identifier for some processor's model description?
I do not know what is this info called but interested in some translation method to go from, for example, `Family 25 Model 80 Stepping 0` to `Intel core i7 7500u` or a numerical identifier.

Comment: Why is the tuple (25, 80, 0) not enough?

Comment: @user3840170 Is the tuple some sort of unique id? I mean the same processor identifies itself.

Comment: Define ‘unique’.

Comment: To be used to search for additional info on a cpu in other datasets like Stanford's http://cpudb.stanford.edu/

Comment: What data sets?

Comment: Like here: http://cpudb.stanford.edu/